# Debugging STMF4 Discovery in Eclipse using GDB

Tags: eclipse, gdb

Hello all: I have never posted on Stackoverflow, but I have always come here for help for years.

I have a question and problem regarding debugging in eclipse using an STLINK STM32 Discovery board. I have looked online for the answer and have followed many tutorials, but I still cannot seem to get it to work correctly. I will try my luck at asking here.

I have set up the eclipse environment correctly with my compiler and gdb server (to my knowledge). First I make sure the server is started before I press debug in eclipse. I am using Atollic STLINK gdb server. I have tried many arm-none-eabi-gdb type exe's while debugging, but they all seem the same. My debug configuration is setup to use arm-none-eabi-gdb on port 61234 (Attolic). When I press debug, the program launches correctly and goes into the debug view in eclipse. The program downloads correctly to my discovery board. I know this because I have gotten debugging to work partially and have stepped through the code without crashing on 'some' occasions depending on the compiled code and debug configuration startup options. The code is a simple LED turn on on the board. If I unplug the usb cable and plug it back in, my code runs fine, because the LEDs light up, so we know the environment is probably set up correctly, because the code downloads to flash via eclipse commands.

The problem is with actual debug steps. 99% of the time the arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe program crashes when in the debug view after I do a few "step into's" with the debugger commands at the top of eclipse. After the first line of my main function is reached, I will try to step into the first line and I get a windows crash of the arm-eabi.exe program. The debug console in eclipse reads a gdb error: .......dwarf2: C10xx Internal Error - unknown CFA rule. Now... depending on how I set the options in the debug configuration with regards to the startup tab, different options produce different results and the following options have been toggled: Halt, resume, break point at : main, etc.. This crash also seems to be dependent on the code being compiled in the main function.

Now, does this have any dependency on which compiler is used with the gdb server and arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe programs? For instance, if I compiled the code with Atollic versus Keil versus code sourcery versus IAR, would the Attollic gdb service + arm-none-eabi-gdb programs be able to work with any compiled code? Are there some missing symbols somewhere not being generated? For reference, I am using an EVAL version of the IAR compiler tool set. If I make a project with the same code in embedded workbench using the STLINK, the code compiles and debugs fine.

What is a CFA rule? Call frame address? Am I not setting up the stack pointer or something in my program? I thought the IAR compiler took care of all that junk in the cstartup.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
LostTime77